# Two div's, first auto-adjust, second fixed width

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a simple subscription form, which consists of two elements:

1. Textbox - Floated left, fills up remaining space.
2. Button  - Floated right, 100px width.

The problem is I can't get the textbox to fill up the remaining width.

```css
.container
{
  width: 100%;
}

.input-field
{
  float: left;
}

.button
{
  float: right;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <input class='input-field'/>

  <div class='button'>Subscribe</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7nyY7/136/

For some reason the textbox is not stretching till the start of the button.

So I tried a different approach and used tables, this is exactly what I'm trying to accomplish, BUT the problem is whenever I add padding to the button and input, they both overflow each other:

http://jsfiddle.net/B46wu/111/

Is it possible to make the textbox end right where the button starts, regardless if the padding is present or not?

Because of the design, I need the textbutton and button to be exactly next to each other. Is this possible without JS? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use **Flexbox**...apply `flex:1` to the `input` to get the remaining space

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.input-field {
  flex: 1;
}

.button {
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <input class='input-field' />

  <div class='button'>
    Subscribe
  </div>
</div>
```

And if you want to use `float` solution you will need to set the width of `input` is equal to `calc(100% - 100px)`

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
}

.input-field {
  float: left;
}

.button {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

input {
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear:both;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <input class='input-field' />
  <div class='button'>
    Subscribe
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply `display: flex` to the container, and add the [flex-grow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow) property  to the textbox, which will make it grow to fill the remaining space.

You can read up on flexbox [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.input-field {
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.5;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.button {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <input class='input-field' />

  <div class='button'>
    Subscribe
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For Accessibility use proper HTML as in the html below buttons instead of

```
<div class='button'>
    Subscribe
  </div>
```

```css
.container{ 
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /*This makes the immediate children into flex items*/
  display: flex;
}

.input-field {
  /*This will span out the whole width minus the 100px for the button*/
  flex: 1;
}

button {
  /*Set button width*/
  width: 100px;
  padding: 5px 20px
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <input class='input-field' />
  <button class='button'>Subscribe</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I had got your layout wrong. However edited code is above.